# Is it possible to reverse the migration of a question?

Tags: support, migration

If my question gets migrated to another site, is it possible somehow to reverse it back to the original site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certain migration paths allowed on every site -- a question can be migrated to one of those sites by quorum of 3k+ rep users. Diamond moderators have the ability to migrate a question anywhere on the network (including to/from Meta sites), so if the question needs to go back to a site that's not in the predefined migration paths, you'll have to flag for moderator attention.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have that much rep. In this case it is possible to place a request to relocate it back.

Comment: @zap If you have an account on the destination site, you should leave a comment on the migrated question explaining why you think it should be returned.

Comment: @zap: You can request a migration from a mod by flagging your question for moderator attention. However, if it was already migrated once, the likelihood of it needing to be re-migrated is much smaller.

Comment: clarify, this is only possible through diamond mod intervention at this point. Regular users *cannot* multiple migrate a question, ever.