# Can we challenge question's migration if it's ordained by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation

I have just answered a question on [StackOverflow regarding an Oracle error ORA-03113](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368630/select-statement-give-ora-03113-on-oracle-11).  The nature of this error means that it requires DBA access to diagnose and resolve.  So I think it is more suited to ServerFault, and voted to close it accordingly.

Except that I wasn't offered the choice of selecting a more approprate Trilogy site.

I think the reason for this is that the question was [originally posted to ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/249480/select-statement-give-ora-03113-on-oracle-11?noredirect=1).  But it was migrated by an SF moderator, Chopper3, and no other voters.  By [his own admission](https://serverfault.com/questions/100475/is-my-new-oracle-dba-talking-sense) Chopper is "no Oracle expert", and I think he has made an error here.

I'm not launching an ad hominem attack, and I'm fine with moderators having super powers.   I just think that we ought to be able to bounce migrated questions back, even if the previous migration was ordained by a moderator.

---

@AdamDavies suggests I post a comment on the original site.  That indeed was the first thing which occurred to me.  However, `comment` is not an option. I don't know whether this is  a reputation thang (I don't use SF much) or because the question was closed by a mod.

I have also flagged the question with the SF moderators, so we'll see.

Comment: What about Flagging the question explaining why you think the migration was wrong? As far as I know, the flag reach several different moderators.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - as I told AdamDavies I did flag the question on SF after I posted here.

Comment: Actually, I believe Adam Davis meant you should comment on the *target* site why it should've stayed on the original site. You can't comment on the original site because a migrated question, by community or mod, will always be locked.

Comment: @Grace - you should flag the original question. The migration history can then be cleared should the moderators agree.

Comment: If you *don't use SF much* then you're most likely not the most qualified to be trying to migrate questions there. Personally, if I were to suggest migration of this question I'd probably suggest [dba.se] instead of [sf].

Comment: @KenWhite - this is an old question which has seen a sudden burst of voting activity.  Back then SE didn't exist in its current form and there were only the three sites - SO, SF and SU.  Obviously I would have voted to migrate the question to DBA if that had been an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration is only allowed once.  Even if a question was migrated by the community, it can't be migrated again.

If you disagree with the migration, whether performed by the community or a moderator, flag the question, or post here (as you have done) and request that it be moved back.

If you can edit it, you might consider editing it so it more clearly defines the question in terms of the site it should appear on.

Also, post a comment on the question itself with your analysis of why it should have remained on the original site.  Others can upvote your comment if they agree, which will give the moderators knowledge of community consensus regarding undoing the migration.

Comment: I searched and found this Meta answer which says questions can be re-migrated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50189/migration-of-questions-choice .  So, hmmm.... But spookily enough I was awhile flagging that question while you were answering mine :)

Comment: @APC No, once it's migrated you can vote to close it, but the "Off Topic" vote doesn't open up options for migration.  Therefore migration is only allowed once, and the question must be flagged with a request for a moderator to un-migrate it, or migrate it to a different site if needed.  If you have 3k rep you can check it out by attempting to migrate this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75805/lag-when-typing-on-superuser-and-se-especially-in-comments-in-ff-and-ie-but-n

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I have flagged the answer I linked to, with a view to getting it retracted or corrected.  WRT commenting, I have edited my question; comments appear to be disabled on the original site.